# Receiving intent if the activity/app is destroyed

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-download-manager

I am developing an app where I need to download a large mp3 from an URL and when it has completed update a database with the path where it has been stored, so that in case there is no internet connection the user can play it.
I have thought in using the downloader system service which is pretty easy to use. After the download is completed, the service broadcast an intent "download.finished". If the app is created, I would receive the intent via a broadcast receiver and update the database. But I dont know what to do in these situations:

- What if the system or user has destroyed the activity/app where the broadcast is created. Would it receive the intent?
- In case it would receive the intent, it would have no sense since the broadcast is hold in a process that would be already kill.
- Is there any way to make the app wait until the broadcast has received the intent?

I would appreciate if you could tell me if I am doing well or there is a better and cleaner way to resolve this.

P.S.: I ve thought implementing my own download service, but since there is already one which comes with the systems, it would be a good way to save time and avoid boilerplate. Thanks.

Comment: You can make an app "wait" for something in the sense of consuming but discarding attempts to make it do anything else, until that condition has been met. But as a rule of general design (and up until Android 5 a technical limitation) you cannot trap the user there unable to navigate away to a different app if they get tired of waiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What if the system or user has destroyed the activity/app where the broadcast is created. Would it receive the intent?

An activity would never receive a broadcast. A `BroadcastReceiver` receives the broadcast. If that `BroadcastReceiver` is registered in the manifest, your app will receive it, even if the app's process from before had been terminated -- Android will fork a fresh process for you.

> Is there any way to make the app wait until the broadcast has received the intent?

Not for any common definition of "make the app wait".

Comment: Thank you for you answer CoomonsWare but I dont get it. I create my broadcast receiver dinamically and pass it my sqlite reference so in the onReceive() method would update the mp3 path. If the system has kill the process, who will create and reasign the sql dependency to the broadcastreceiver?
By the way, is this ok or should i implement this in other way?

Comment: @Quark: "who will create and reasign the sql dependency to the broadcastreceiver" -- nobody. The broadcasts will be ignored. If you want to respond to this broadcast when your process is not running, register the receiver in the manifest. "is this ok" -- I have no idea what "this" is, let alone whether it is OK.

Comment: I have read again broadcast receivers docs and I understand how it works. It seems I just need to use the programmatically defined broadcast receiver to update the UI in case the app is on. But it wont solve my main problem: After request a download via downloader system service, how can I update the SQL database with the downloaded file path if the app is closed?
Instead of saving the path on the database,is there any better way to check if the file has been downloaded when the app starts and loads the data so the user is aware it will be played from the SD card? I.E. calling file.exist()?Thx

Comment: @Quark: Register the receiver in the manifest, then have it kick off an `IntentService` that can update your database.